# Can someone point me to a particularly good resource on JPA/Hibernate lazy/eager fetching?

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa, lazy-evaluation

Looking for a really good article that includes strategies/bugs/workarounds. I would prefer a pure JPA solution but I know Hibernate offers a lot of extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of what you're looking for exactly. But to put is simply, `LAZY` simply means that a child association won't be loaded while loading the parent, it will be loaded when explicitly asked by the application. EAGER means that a child association will be loaded while loading the parent.

In general, `LAZY` is better performance wise (when you just don't need or want to load a whole objects graph). But depending on the situation, it might just be suboptimal or lead to the famous "N+1 SELECT" problem (while iterating over a list of N entities, accessing a `LAZY` association will fire another SELECT, resulting in 1+N SELECT at the end). Depending on the situation, an `EAGER` association - or a `FETCH JOIN` to prefetch the association - is preferable.

So I don't know what part is unclear but here are some resources that might help:

- Hibernate wiki

  - [A Short Primer On Fetching Strategies](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/AShortPrimerOnFetchingStrategies) (from the pre JPA era but the concepts still apply)
  - [Some explanations on lazy loading (one-to-one)](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/Someexplanationsonlazyloadingone-to-one)
- Articles

  - [Hibernate: Understanding Lazy Fetching](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t20533.html)
  - [Hibernate: Tuning Lazy Fetching](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t33002.html)

See also:

- Hibernate Core documentation

  - [14.3. Associations and joins](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins)
  - [19.1. Fetching strategies](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching)
- JPA 1.0 specification

  - Section 4.4.5.3 "Fetch Joins"

Comment: The concepts are clear, I'm looking for a discussion of strategies. I'll check out your links, tnx.

Answer (score 0):

Book *"Java Persistence with Hibernate"* by Bauer and King, Chapter 13 *"Optimizing fetching and caching"*. You should be able to find a copy of the book online.